# jQuery Editable datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm doing a project which uses **jQuery,MVC**.
for that i'm using the jquery datatable so i need to add a editable datatable,**which user can add data by clicking at a table row....and when i click a button all the data in the table shuold pass to the Controller** to add to the sql database
i tyied jEditable but it didnt work, 
Please help me to do this.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery datatables does not support submitting data to the server. It can only grab and populate data from the server.

You could use jquery to do an ajax call and collect the datatable's data to pass back to the server manually.

Comment: Use html table with in a <form> tag, then add textboxes to the html table columns <td><%= html.textbox("txtTextBoxId")%></td>, then convert it to a jquery datatable.....then you will get a datatble with editable columns.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you use Flexigrid for jQuery . It is the best client side data table I ever met. Details can be found [here](http://flexigrid.info/)