# Edit an entity using DataTables (JQuery) and send it via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, jeditable

I m using Datatables for my data, but now i want that the user can modify the data stored on the db. So  I read that i can use jeditable, but I do not know how to send data to the server when you press the enter key. I read this question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920798/jquery-editable-datatable) but i don't know how to implement it. Can anyone help me? I need to do this with the second table example :

```
<form action="/repairServlet" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="aggiorna">
<input type="hidden" name="keycar" value="<%=KeyFactory.keyToString(keycar)%>">
<input type="hidden" name="plate" value="<%=repair.getProperty("plate")%>">
<input type="hidden" name="km" value="<%=repair.getProperty("km")%>">
 <input type="hidden" name="keyRepair" value="<%=KeyFactory.keyToString(repairKey)%>">
    <table width="200" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Data Riparazione</td>
                <td><input type="date" name="date" value="<%=(String)repair.getProperty("date") %>" /></td>
                <td>Stato</td>
                <td><select  name="selectStato" size="3" multiple="multiple"
                    tabindex="1">
                        <option value="1">In corso</option>
                        <option value="2">Sospesa</option>
                        <option value="3">Conclusa</option>
                </select>
                <td>KM</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="km" value="<%=(String)repair.getProperty("km") %>" /></td>
                <td>Targa</td>
                <td><h4>
                        <label> &nbsp <%=(String)repair.getProperty("plate") %></label>
                    </h4></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>



    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display"
        id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Indice</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Descrizione</th>
                <th>Quantità</th>
                <th>Prezzo</th>
                <th>Totale</th>
                <th>Azioni</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <%for(Entity lr : listaRepairs){ %>    

            <tr>
                <td>ddd</td>
                <td><% out.print(lr.getProperty("type"));%></td>
                <td><% out.print(lr.getProperty("description"));%></td>
                <td><% out.print(lr.getProperty("qta"));%></td>
                <td><% out.print(lr.getProperty("price"));%></td>
                <td><% out.print(lr.getProperty("tot"));%></td> 
                <td><input type="submit" name="Aggiorna" /></td>                
            </tr>       


            <%-- <tr>
                <td>ddd</td>

                <td><input type="text" name="type" value="<%=lr.getProperty("type") %>" />
                     <input type="hidden" name="keyLineRepair" value="<%=KeyFactory.keyToString(lr.getKey())%>">
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="description" value="<%=lr.getProperty("description") %>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="qta" value="<%=lr.getProperty("qta") %>"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price" value="<%=lr.getProperty("price") %>" /></td>
                <td><%=lr.getProperty("tot") %></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Aggiorna" /></td>
            </tr> --%>
            <%} %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Your question should be "how to submit data by pressing enter key in html". It doesn't really relate to appengine.

Comment: i changed the title. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.edit').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php');
 });
```

> Code above does several things: Elements with class edit become editable. Editing starts with single mouse click. Form input element is text. Width and height of input element matches the original element. If users clicks outside form changes are discarded. Same thing happens if users hits ESC. When user hits ENTER browser submits text to save.php at www.example.com.

So in your code, give the table an id and then do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         $('#mytable').editable('http://<your domain/repairServlet');
     });
```

Comment: but what send to the servlet? Are parameter in the url? Because i did the table Jeditable and link to my servlet, but nothing appear

Comment: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable - take a look at "what is sent to server".  It should send " id=elements_id&value=user_edited_content"

Comment: I read it. So  
`id   : 'elementid',
name : 'newvalue'`

newvalue and id what are?

Comment: By default it will send through id=<your element id>&name=<your updated value>. Check your logs, you'll see what information it's posting. Or get fiddler to see what information is being posted. http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: Ok. I'm Downloading Fiddle! Thanks! But how can I get the correct value in the servlet? example in the normal post we have site.com/servlet?username=x&password=y  and catch it with getParameter("x"). how can I do in this case?

Comment: If it's a post, you'll need to look in the post arguments. You may be able to do getParameter("id") and getparameter("value).

Comment: So the script send only one value at once?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32975/discussion-between-bert-and-frank)